# Handling zero as amount format in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have an amount column which needs to be in `225,000.00` format, for which below is the query that i have written

```
Select TRIM(to_char(pen_amt,'999,999,999,999,999.99')) as PenAmount from transact;
```

Above query is giving correct result for all values except `0`, for 0, its coming as `.00`, instead of it, it should come as `00.00`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 0 where you want the precision to start.

```
Select TRIM(to_char(pen_amt,'999,999,999,999,909.99')) as PenAmount from transact;
```